# Showing $1/\left(\frac{1}{\cos(x)} + \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having a hard time with some basic rule of fractions that I just don't get.  I'm told to show that $\frac{1}{\sec(x)+\tan(x)} = \sec(x)-\tan(x)$.  I start with the left hand side and convert it to

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos(x)} + \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}}.\tag{Step 1}\label1$$

From here I would normally remove the main 1 in the numerator and invert the fractional denominators by performing the division.

So

$$\frac{1}{1} \times \frac{\cos(x)}{1} + \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}\tag{Step 2}.\label2$$

Doing this lead me down a path that just doesn't work.  The book answer shows them taking the denominator of each fraction in the denominator in \ref{1}
 (meaning the $\cos(x)$) and just multiply it out of the main fraction.

So they show as: $$\frac{\cos(x)}{1 + \sin(x)} \tag{Step 3}.$$

But this is driving me crazy because their \ref{2} can not be an equality for my step to.  I've tried it with basic fractions and just can't see it.
Can someone tell me which one is right?

Comment: and maybe someone can tell me why my mathjax didn't work?  I thought I got it right? no?

Comment: I edited it...pls approve

Comment: @maybedave MathJax code must be enclosed in dollar signs (there may be other problems but that is the main one)

Comment: @xcoderX.  Sorry, I've not done this before, how do I approve?

Comment: @maybedave $$\frac{1}{1/a+b/a}\neq a + \frac{a}{b}$$

Comment: @The Great Duck.  Thank you!  It looks right now :)

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing equation numbering and changing inline fractions to display style ones.  Please proofread the question to ensure that the meaning of the question remains the same.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I don’t know why. But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{b}{a}} \neq \frac{a}{1}+\frac{a}{b}. \tag{1} $$
To see that, put $a=b=1$ for example.
Rather, by using the fact that
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{b}{a} =  \frac{1+b}{a}, \tag{2}$$
we can write $(1)$ as
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{b}{a}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1+b}{a}} =\frac{a}{1+b}. \tag{3}$$
In your case, $a = \cos(x)$ and $b=\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1}{\sec(x)+\tan(x)} = \dfrac{\sec(x)-\tan(x)}{\sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x)} = \dfrac{\sec(x)-\tan(x)}{1}=\sec(x)-\tan(x)$

If you need to justify the denominator:

$(\sec(x)-\tan(x))(\sec(x)+\tan(x)) = \sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x) = \dfrac{1-\sin^2(x) }{\cos^2(x)} = \dfrac{\cos^2(x) }{\cos^2(x)} =1$

Comment: Thanks Henry.  But I want to know how $\frac{cos(x)}{1 + sin(x)}$ is an identity for $\frac{1}{sec(x) + tan(x)}$ when $\frac{cos(x)}{1 + sin(x)}$ does not equal $\frac{cos(x)}{1}$ + $\frac{cos(x)}{sin(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\sec x+ \tan x} =\frac{1}{\frac1{\cos x}+ \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} =\frac{\cos x}{1+ \sin x}=\frac{\cos x}{1+ \sin x} \cdot \frac{1- \sin x}{1- \sin x} =\\=\frac{\cos x(1-\sin x)}{1- \sin^2 x} =\frac{\cos x-\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2 x} = \sec x -\tan x $$

Comment: So let me re-ask the question in another way.  Is $\frac{cos(x)}{1 + sin(x)}$ equal to $\frac{cos(x)}{1}$ + $\frac{cos(x)}{sin(x)}$?

Comment: @maybedave no you can't equate the two terms, since in general $$\frac{a}{b+c}\neq \frac{a}{b}+ \frac{a}{c}$$ what is true (for $a \neq 0$) is that $$\frac{b+c}{a}= \frac{b}{a}+ \frac{c}{a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1{\sec x-\tan x}=\sec x+\tan x$$ can be written $$\sec^2x-\tan^2x=1$$

or

$$\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=1.$$